# How do i get the seal_ids that have a manytomany field passed to a form before a user creates a dispatch

Tags: python, django

i have two models a Seal model and a Dispatch model, where there is a seal_id field that has a manytomany relationship with Seal model. I want to only list seal_ids on the modelform where a dispatch seal_location_status="Received" and station_from = request.user.station.

here are my models

```
class Seal(models.Model):
    s_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)  # Auto-generated unique ID
    seal_no = models.CharField(max_length=12, unique=True)
    imei = models.CharField(max_length=15, unique=True)
    seal_type = models.ForeignKey(SealType,to_field='name', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)

    
class Dispatch(models.Model):
    STATUS_CHOICES=(
            ('Dispatched','Dispatched'),
            ('Received','Received')

    )
    dispatch_id = UniqueIDGeneratorField()
    seal_id = models.ManyToManyField(Seal,related_name='seals')  # Change to CharField with appropriate max_length
    # seal_type = models.ForeignKey(SealType,to_field='name', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    handler = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    station_from = models.ForeignKey(Station, related_name='dispatches_from', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    station_to = models.ForeignKey(Station, related_name='dispatches_to', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    dispatched_by = models.ForeignKey(CustomUser,on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True)
    seal_location_status = models.CharField(max_length=20, choices=STATUS_CHOICES)
```

here is my modelform

class DispatchForm(forms.ModelForm):
class Meta:

```
    model = Dispatch
    exclude = ['dispatched_by','station_from' ]
    fields = ('seal_id','handler','station_to','seal_location_status')
    widgets = {
                'seal_id': forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple
                    }
```